# PHP : File Upload on chrome browser

Tags: php, google-chrome

I am trying to upload an image via simple image upload script in PHP.

But, there is one problem which my testers have pointed out.

They are saying when they browse the image and then change the name of the source image and proceed with the upload.. Its not working.

> Like before browe it was abc.jpg and after browe but before
>   uploading made it abc1.jpg

I tried to figure out this issue and found that when the above case is done I encounter a page not found error.

Can anyone tell me how can I fix this problem?

This is chrome specific only!

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and upload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
echo "Size=".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"];
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
//echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"].'--'.$target_file;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean they "change the name"? If they're pulling a file from their computer and changing it in the dialog box, then yeah... file not found. You need to provide an input for them to allow to change the name.

Comment: @Fred-ii- edited my question

Comment: they can't rename a file during upload. Not without changing the name of it on their computer first. I doubt this is specific to google chrome. They are trying to upload a file from their computer that doesn't exist, because it's renamed in their dialog box. I don't know how else I can explain this. See my first comment on giving them the option to give it a custom name.

Comment: take this analogy for example. You send a letter out to a friend who lives at 123 Maple Lane, but then the person living there changed the house address to 123a. The postman doesn't know where to put the letter in, the address doesn't exist.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I understand what you are saying. And If at all I talk to testers and convince them on this point. Then how can I write my code to catch this as exception? Still my code should know that this has happened so that I can show proper message.. or do something else.

Comment: you can try a conditional statement: `if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']))` or `if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']))`

Comment: Nope.. this doesn't works, already tried.. As soon as upload button is clicked, control does not goes to the upload.php page, so any check would not get a chance to execute. It says page not found.

Comment: page not found means server issues. check your logs. and... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: I am sorry I am bothering you too much, but error reporting does not help either. On upload it still says page not found and if I refresh the page once then the notices and all appear.